# PHP Laravel: SoapClient Issue Fatal Error: call to a member function __soapCall() on null

Tags: php, laravel, web-services, soap, soap-client

I'm working on a project using a SOAP interface to another server and am having some serious issues getting this to work. SOAP is not something I am very familiar with and I have been having a really tough time finding help for this anywhere. Even the people who developed the WSDL file have no ability to help me...

I have a WSDL file - https://sdkdev.wagefiler.com/WageFilerWS/wagefiler.asmx?WSDL

For starters, I need to be able to create an account. The code below works but returns an error of "-999" which is undefined according to the developers of the WSDL and the other server side. They told me to make sure I'm passing an instance of an AccountRequest Object... but nothing I do seems to help.

This is my SoapController.php file. My route points to "demo". It literally returns an error -999.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\SoapWrapper;
use Sentinel;
use App\backendInformation;
use SoapClient;
use SoapHeader;
use SoapParam;
use SoapVar;

class SoapController extends Controller
{

public function demo()
{

    $WSDL = 'https://sdkdev.wagefiler.com/WageFilerWS/wagefiler.asmx?WSDL';
    $user = Sentinel::getUser();
    $backendInfo = backendInformation::where('user_id', $user['id'])->first();
    $b = new backendInformation();
    $b->user_id  = $user['id'];
    $b->username = $user['email'];
    $b->password = crypt($b['username'], '$5$rounds=5000$anexamplestringforsalt$');
    $b->customername = $user['first_name'] . ' ' . $user['last_name'];
    $b->useremail = $user['email'];
    $b->autoemail = $user['email'];



    $options = [
        'trace' => true,
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
    ];

    $credentials = [
        'ClientID' => 'XXXX'
    ];


    $data = array(
        'sequence' => array(
            'UserID' => $user->nelco_user_id,
            'Password' => $user->nelco_password,
            'Email' => $b->useremail,
            'ClientId' => config('global.nelco_client_id'),
            'FName' => $user->first_name,
            'LName' => $user->last_name,
            'EIN' => $user->ein,
            'Addr1' => $user->addr1,
            'City' => $user->city,
            'State' => $user->state,
            'Zip' => $user->zip,
            'Phone' => $user->phone,
        ),
    );

    $client = new SoapClient($WSDL, $options); // null for non-wsdl mode

    $param = new SoapParam(new SoapVar($data, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT), 'AccountRequest');

    $client->__soapCall('AccountSetup',array($param));

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($client);
    echo "</pre>";

}
}
```

The return value looks like this -

```
object(SoapClient)#267 (12) {
  ["trace"]=>
  int(1)
  ["_stream_context"]=>
  resource(8) of type (stream-context)
  ["_soap_version"]=>
  int(1)
  ["sdl"]=>
  resource(10) of type (SOAP SDL)
  ["__last_request"]=>
  string(972) "
    UserIDbob@bob.comPassword$5$rounds=5000$anexamplestringf$ADNI5REUuQNRHFXv3tId        EhLg65jb4Jc0csmuI4ENQu6Emailbob@bob.comClientId8266FNameBobLNameMcBobbersonEI    N123123123Addr1123 Bobs PlaceCityBobvilleStateokZip73115Phone123-123-1234
"
  ["httpsocket"]=>
  resource(11) of type (stream)
  ["_use_proxy"]=>
  int(0)
  ["httpurl"]=>
  resource(12) of type (SOAP URL)
  ["__last_request_headers"]=>
  string(259) "POST /WageFilerWS/wagefiler.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: sdkdev.wagefiler.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/7.1.8-1ubuntu1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://localhost/WageFiler/WageFiler/AccountSetup"
Content-Length: 972

"
  ["__last_response_headers"]=>
  string(330) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 25 Oct 2017 20:37:54 GMT
Content-Length: 382
Set-Cookie: BIGipServerpool_sdkdev.wagefiler.com_443=3389265580.47873.0000;     path=/; Httponly; Secure
"
  ["_cookies"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["BIGipServerpool_sdkdev.wagefiler.com_443"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(21) "3389265580.47873.0000"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "/"
      [2]=>
      string(20) "sdkdev.wagefiler.com"
    }
  }
  ["__last_response"]=>
  string(382) "-999"
}
```

Comment: what happens if you call the function like this   $client->__soapCall('AccountSetup',[$data]);  I can't load the wsdl ..

Comment: I get almost the exact same output

Comment: object(SoapClient)#275 (12) {
      ["trace"]=>
      int(1)
      ["_stream_context"]=>
      resource(8) of type (stream-context)
      ["_soap_version"]=>
      int(1)
      ["sdl"]=>
      resource(10) of type (SOAP SDL)
      ["__last_request"]=>
      string(238) "
    
    "

Comment: It literally shows nothing in the last request... the response wont let me put the full output so I trimmed it down

Comment: Have you been able to test it in soapui  >

Comment: I didnt know soapui was a thing... this is my first real experience using SOAP at all.

Comment: I do know that the desktop software my company writes is written in delphi from the 90s, and it interacts with this soap server just fine... but none of us can get PHP to interact with it at all.

Comment: SOAPUI works fine.

Comment: download fiddle, catch the request/responses and check the content.

Comment: Error loading [https://sdkdev.wagefiler.com/WageFilerWS/wagefiler.asmx?WSDL]: java.lang.Exception: Failed to load url;  Otherwise I think you have some issues with objects in the soap request...

Comment: I dont know why the WSDL file didnt work for you, but the correct link is



`https ://sdkdev.wagefiler.com/WageFilerWS/wagefiler.asmx?WSDL`

and I just tested it in the browser. - I had to add a space after the https so that it'd render

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the SOAP documentation for the WSDL was wrong. They were requiring a bunch of fields that we weren't sending during testing. The WSDL file shows them when you closely examine it but the documentation says they are specifically optional.